# While loop to fetch data inside for loop not working properly

Tags: php, oracle, for-loop, oracle-call-interface

I have split my string into 9 elements and then for each of those elements, I am trying to fetch data from a table using where condition. But I am getting values for the first split elements. Suppose my first string element is Bislol 5 mg Tablet and using this I am getting code BS01. And my second split element is Clavusef 250 mg Tablet and for this also I am getting code BS01. I am giving my code below. Need a solution in this regard.

```
<?php

     $id = $_POST["MPO_CODE"];

     $categoryid="Bislol 5 mg Tablet, Bislol Max 2.5/5 mg Tablet, Clavusef".
     " 250 mg Tablet, Cosarin Tablet, Diohes 500 mg Tablet, Finix 20 mg ".
     "Tablet, Finix 20 mg Tablet, Hypen-SR 1.5 mg Tablet, Peptofit 200 ml ".
     "Suspension";

     $cat_ids = (explode(",", $categoryid));
     $count = count($cat_ids);

     $conn = oci_connect("");
     for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
     {                
         $catid = $cat_ids[$i];
         $p = oci_parse($conn2,"SELECT P_DESC   FROM 
                                 SAM_PRODUCT
                                 WHERE P_DESC= '$catid' " );
         oci_execute($p);
         while ($row = oci_fetch_array($p, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
             $P_DESC= $row["P_DESC"];
         }

         echo $catid;
         echo "<br>";
         echo $P_DESC;

         echo "<br>";       
         echo "<br>";
         echo "<br>";
         echo "<br>";
     }
```

Comment: Make sure you `trim` the values, because every element after the first will start with a space, which most likely won't match your database value. Also, using a `foreach` on `$cat_ids` might be a bit easier than getting it by key value.

Comment: Or you can explode using ", " (with a space) instead of "," (without a space)